# New instance of class or something different?

Tags: ruby

I have seen here and there code like this one

```
Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = %q{casein}
  s.version = "3.1.11"
....
```

Can someone explain me what is the idea behind "do |s|" ?

Comment: Search for "ruby block". I'm surprised it hasn't been .. encountered before. It is used in many places: `.each` being a very common example. `do |params| .. end` is the *same* as `{|params| ..}` with different tokens used for the block start/end, if that was the source of confusion.

Comment: Oh, and, *please **put the real question** in the title*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of using blocks in ruby. Block is a chunk of code that you can pass to a method (`new` is just a regular method).

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts "doing some work"
    yield('Foo') if block_given?
  end
end

Foo.new do |s|
  puts "output from #{s}"
end
# >> doing some work
# >> output from Foo
```

Here initializer in `Foo` calles a block (if one is given) and passes it a parameters. Block then can receive that parameter and do its work.

[Educational reading](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

it's an argument that gets exposed to block by initializer of `Specification`

things probably look like this in that class:

```
class Specification
  def initialize
    # ...
    yield self
    # ...
  end
end
```

that `yield` executes a block and passes a single argument to it - `self` (it might be any other object so better go check the source)

code block usually looks like this:

```
do |arguments, list|
  # code here
end
```

but arguments are optional(unless it's lambda and you will get exception for too few or too many)